# What is the best way to update cluster icon using gmaps4rails

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, markerclusterer

I am a big fan of gmaps4rails gem and it has been working well and very flexible.

However, I cannot seem to clear and update the Cluster marker easily and I cannot find similar solutions on Stackoverflow that is using this gem.

In my javascript, I am using the following methods to filter out visible markers. But Gmaps.map.clearClusterer doesn't seem to respond to click event. I am able to show and hide markers properly but not able to clear cluster markers nor update the cluster markers with new number. What should I do differently?

```
  var VisibleMarker=function(){
    var filtered=_.filter(Gmaps.map.markers,function(marker){   
       return marker.building_type == SELECT;
     }); //end of _.filter
    return filtered
  }//end of VisibleMarker

  var applyFilters=function(){
    var VisibleArray=VisibleMarker()
    _.each(Gmaps.map.markers,function(marker){
         Gmaps.map.hideMarker(marker)
     })
        Gmaps.map.clearClusterer()
    _.each(VisibleArray,function(marker){
         Gmaps.map.showMarker(marker)
     }) 
        Gmaps.map.createClusterer(VisibleArray)

   };//end of applyFilters
```

UPDATE:

How should I properly call the addMarkers() method in the MarkerClusterer Class?
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

I used this line:

> Gmaps.map.addMarkers(VisibleArray)

But it calls this function instead:

```
Gmaps4Rails.prototype.addMarkers = function(new_markers) {
this.markers = this.markers.concat(new_markers);
this.create_markers();
return this.adjustMapToBounds();
};
```

Comment: Can't really dig into this but I'm halfway to complete js refactoring/cleanup for the gem. Hope the problems will disappear then (but there'll be some backward incompatibilities)

Comment: Just jad a look at the source code, should be fine... What if you try in console? Any error?

Comment: Gmaps.map.clearClusterer() is working properly in the console. But when I am trying to add it back in with the Gmaps.map.createClusterer(VisibleArray), no markers is created. I was also trying to use the addMarkers method in the MarkerClusterer Class http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html by using  Gmaps.map.addMarkers(VisibleArray), but no markers show either

Comment: You should not use `add` since your markers were already added. You should use `show`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions about "add". I decided to use backend to calculate clustering instead. So I didn't end up using the MarkerClusterer method.